# Aggregation calculations on aws quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am exploring Quicksight as BI UI.
There are some required calculations that I am after and I couldnt find how can they be done.

1. How would you implement "count distinct" ?
2. How would you present an amount as percentage of total or of previous item in the series (I am trying to present funnel data in percentage)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Not Possible for now

Here is Reply from QuickSight Team -

> We understand the need to count(distinct) and are working to add this into the product as soon as possible.

2.Not Possible 
QS teams Reply :

> We currently do not support calculations across rows, but this is a planned item on our roadmap

Comment: This answer needs to be updated as it is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The "count(distinct)" function is now available in Quicksight.

Comment: Could you add a link to a changelog/documentation/release notes and/or provide the version since when it is available?